# Luhn algorithm check digit in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm struggling with [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to calculate check digit for 14 digit length number. I found this solution [here](http://practicalagility.com/luhn-algorithm-for-salesforce-formula-field/comment-page-1/#comment-399688), hut it's only for 6 digit number. If I want to create it for more digits I'll get over formula compiled characters limit.

Here's formula for 6 digit number

```
MOD(10 - MOD(
         IF(
               MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c) ,10)*2 > 9,
               MOD(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c) ,10)*2,10) + 1,
               MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c) ,10)*2
           ) +
           FLOOR(MOD(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 100)/10,10)) +
           IF(
               (FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 1000)/100)*2)>9,
               MOD(FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 1000)/100)*2,10)+1,
               (FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 1000)/100)*2)
           ) +
           FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 10000)/1000) +
           IF(
               (FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 1000)/100)*2)>9,
               MOD(FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 1000)/100)*2,10)+1,
               (FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 1000)/100)*2)
           ) +
           FLOOR(MOD(VALUE(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c), 10000)/1000)
       ,10)
  ,10)
```

Any idea how can I do it?

> [Luhn algorithm (from wikipedia):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) The formula verifies a number
>   against its included check digit, which is usually appended to a
>   partial account number to generate the full account number. This
>   number must pass the following test:
>
> 1. From the rightmost digit, which is the check digit, moving left, double the value of every second digit; if the product of this
>      doubling operation is greater than 9 (e.g., 8 × 2 = 16), then sum the
>      digits of the products (e.g., 16: 1 + 6 = 7, 18: 1 + 8 = 9).
> 2. Take the sum of all the digits.
> 3. If the total modulo 10 is equal to 0 (if the total ends in zero) then the number is valid according to the Luhn formula; else it is not
>      valid. Assume an example of an account number "7992739871" that will
>      have a check digit added, making it of the form 7992739871x.
>
> The check digit (x) is obtained by computing the sum of digits then
>   computing 9 times that value modulo 10 (in equation form, (67 × 9 mod
>   10)). In algorithm form:
>
> 1. Compute the sum of the digits (67).
> 2. Multiply by 9 (603).
> 3. The last digit, 3, is the check digit. Thus, x=3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the field must be "Text" in order to use the MID function.
Can you check that one and tell me if it works ?

```
MOD( 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 14, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 13, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 13, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 13, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 13, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) + 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 12, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 11, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 11, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 11, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 11, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) + 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 10, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 9, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 9, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 9, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 9, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) + 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 8, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 7, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 7, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 7, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 7, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) + 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 6, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 5, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 5, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 5, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 5, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) + 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 4, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 3, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 3, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 3, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 3, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) + 

VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 2, 1))+ 

IF( VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 1, 1))<5, 
VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 1, 1))*2, 
VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 1, 1))*2),1,1))+VALUE(MID(TEXT(VALUE(MID(wir_GSAP_Inv_No__c, 1, 1))*2),2,1)) 
) 

, 10) != 0
```

It works for me, and the validation rule is way longer than that because I check if it is a number with ISNUMBER, if the length is 14, the country, etc.
Si I don't think you are going to hit the length limit (I may be mistaken though, because my field name is shorter than yours)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I get an error:  Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number). As I understand the code, you are just checking if the the number is Mod 10 valid, but I actually need to calculate the check digit.

Answer (score 1):

What I have below returns the checksum digit for a 14 digit number stored in a text field.

Please note that as written, it only works for values that are exactly 14 digit numbers, but it should be easy enough to adapt for other sized numbers.

```
VALUE (
RIGHT (
TEXT (
9
*
(
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 2 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10 
 , 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 2 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 
 , 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 2 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)
 +
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 3 ) , 1 ) ) * 1
 +
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 4 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 4 ) , 1 ) ) * 2
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 4 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)
 +
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 5 ) , 1 ) ) * 1
 +
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 6 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 6 ) , 1 ) ) * 2
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 6 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)
 +
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 7 ) , 1 ) ) * 1
 +
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 8 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 8 ) , 1 ) ) * 2
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 8 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)
 +
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 9 ) , 1 ) ) * 1
 +
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 10 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 10 ) , 1 ) ) * 2
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 10 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)
 +
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 11 ) , 1 ) ) * 1
 +
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 12 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 12 ) , 1 ) ) * 2
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 12 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)
 +
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 13 ) , 1 ) ) * 1
 +
IF ( 
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 14 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 < 10
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 14 ) , 1 ) ) * 2
,
VALUE ( LEFT ( RIGHT ( analysis__X14DigitNumber__c , 14 ) , 1 ) ) * 2 - 9
)

) 
)
,
1
)
)
```