# Luhn Algorithm: How to get check digit of MOD 10v1 in Batch Apex Class?

Tags: apex, batch

I would like to ask some help on how I can get the Mod 10 check digit of Contact.DonorID.
the result should be

```
Contact.CRN__c = Contact.DonorID + CheckDigit
```

Just like this:

> Check Digit is **2**
>
> CRN: 0018457**2**

It is my first time to do it and I don't have any idea, I've been struggling for 3 days searching about it. I found this link -- [Luhn algorithm check digit in formula field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79536/luhn-algorithm-check-digit-in-formula-field) but it is using formula field, so, it can't help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you made an attempt at it? The Wikipedia article linked to by the formula field question does give a pseudocode implementation. If you have tried to code this, please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and point to a specific sport that you're stuck on.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't format the code well in reply.

Comment: @DerekF, I tried this code. But wasn't sure. Is it correct? Is it Mod 10?

`String donorId = '0115839';
Integer sum = 0;
Integer len = donorId.length();
for(Integer i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
   Integer num = Integer.ValueOf(donorId.substring(i,i+1));
   if ( math.mod(i , 2) == math.mod(len, 2) )
   {
       Integer n = num * 2;
       sum += (n / 10) + ( math.mod(n, 10));
       System.debug('Output1: ' + sum);
       String result = donorId + sum;
       System.debug('CRN: ' + result);
   }
   else{
        sum += num;
        System.debug('Output2: ' + sum);
   }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it and it's working! I'll share my apex code. You can test it on Anonymous Window.

```
                String donorId = Contact.DonorID__c;
                Integer sum = 0;
                String resultCRN;
                Integer l = donorId.length();
                
                for(Integer i=l-1;i>=0;i--){
                    Integer num = Integer.ValueOf(donorId.substring(i,i+1));
                    if (math.mod(i, 2) == math.mod(l, 2))
                    {
                        Integer n = num * 2;
                        sum += (n / 10) + (math.mod(n, 10));
                    }
                    else{
                        sum += num;
                    }
                }
                resultCRN= donorId + sum;
                Contact.CRN__c = resultCRN;
                System.debug('Donor ID is: ' + donorId );
                System.debug('Check digit result is: ' + sum);
                System.debug('CRN is: ' + resultCRN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, you just need to implement the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

```
static Integer accumulate(String[] digits, Boolean validate) {
    // This algorithm goes from the *left*, so we need to know which to double
    Integer checkSize = validate? 1: 0;
    Integer accumulator = 0;
    while(!digits.isEmpty()) {
        Integer nextDigit = Integer.valueOf(digits.remove(0));
        // We should double the value when true
        if((digits.size()&1) == checkSize) {
            nextDigit <<= 1;
            // And "add together" the individual digits when 10+
            if(nextDigit > 9) {
                nextDigit -= 9;
            }
        }
        accumulator += nextDigit;
    }
    return accumulator;
}
// Returns true if the valid Luhn check digit present
public static Boolean validateLuhnCheckDigit(String source) {
    return 0 == Math.mod(accumulate(source.split(''), true), 10);
}
// Returns the check digit for a given string
public static String calculateLuhnCheckDigit(String source) {
    return ''+Math.mod(accumulate(source.split(''), false) * 9, 10);
}
```

No error checking is provided, and is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand the code.. and I don't know how to convert these to Apex Batch code.

Comment: @juandelacruz `Contact.CRN__c = Contact.DonorId + calculateLuhnCheckDigit(Contact.DonorId);`

Comment: I got it now. I'll post the code here for the correct answer.

Comment: @juandelacruz My code is perfectly correct. If you're not sure how to call a function, you might want to do [some reading](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm).

Comment: Yes, I believe you sir.. I was just looking for easier solution. Thanks sir.